# Push failed: Failed with error:

Tags: android, git, android-studio, azure-devops

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 with Microsoft Team services plugin 1.123.0. After the last update, I cannot push commits to my remote server (Microsoft Team Services), i just got this error:

> Push failed: Failed with error:

Nothing else. What can I do ?

Comment: I tried in Git Bash with: git push origin master, but nothing happens.

Comment: I have the same versions (Android studio 2.3.3, team services plugin 1.123.0) on windows, and I can push to remote git repo successfully. What if you restart andrio studio and update the the credentail for the VSTS git repo (File -> settings -> version control -> team services/TFS -> select the repo you were push failed -> update cerdential), the then push again?

Comment: And doesn't there has no message after `Push failed: Failed with error:`?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I tried to enter credentials multiple time and it doesn't work. And there is no message after "Push failed: Failed with error:". I have multiple commits locally waiting to be pushed to remote. I doesn't work after 22.8. I think.

Comment: But I use the same version as you, and it can push successful. Did you install the android studio with default setting or change some settings?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Yes, I use it for two years on a project. Didn't change anything, nor os, nor hw. I just get updates.

Comment: Did you restart after update android studio?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Yes, each time in this period (22.8. - today). It is wierd that there is no message after "Push failed: Failed with error:". Is there log in Anroid Studio that I can see for this ?

Comment: Can you add a screen shot while also showing the console window (in Version control Tab)?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/4nqSJ. Do you need something else ?

Comment: Can you select the **Console** Tab (the screen shot is selecting Local Changes Tab now)?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT In my Console Tab window there is just this line when I try push: `09:00:05.230: [MyProject] git -c core.quotepath=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master`. In Event Log: `Push failed: Failed with error: `

Comment: So what's the result if you execute the command `git -c core.quotepath=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master` manually in terminal window?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT When I run `D:\MyProject>git -c core.quotepath=false push --progress --porcelain origin
 refs/heads/master:master`
I get: 
`D:\MyProject>`. Nothing.

Comment: Please check with below aspects: **1.** what's the size of files to be pushed, are they big enough? **2.** what's the `git status` says? **3.** check if the remote URL is correct by `git remote -v`, and make sure you are accessible to the URL.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT: 1. Regarding the size, it is relatively small project, whole project directory have 215Mb and I have: 28 files changed, 180 insertions(+), 264 deletions(-) for this push. 2. Git status says https://imgur.com/a/ubUC6, 3. `git remove -v` gives me origin  `https://my.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyApp/_git/MyApp (fetch)
origin  https://my.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyApp/_git/MyApp (push)`, 4. I entered credentials for Team services multiple times, with no error.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT: What I see as a difference when I update credentials from Android Studio, is that my URL is now: `https://my.visualstudio.com/MyApp/_git/MyApp`, but when I go through web interface of Team services, (clone), url is: `https://my.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyApp/_git/MyApp`

Comment: If the git repo name is same as the team project name, the URL should be `https://my.visualstudio.com/_git/MyApp`. You can change the URL in android  studio terminal window: `git remote set-url origin https://my.visualstudio.com/_git/MyApp`. Then you can add the credential for it and push again.

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I tried with both URL-s but it is the same, when I try push `Push failed: Failed with error: `. I enter credentials correctly, it passes.

Comment: That's weird. So no matter push changes by android studio, terminal or git bash, the changes actually not pushed? Does the situation only for the current local repo or all the repos including other remote repos?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I installed new version of Git for Windows and it works now. It seems that was a problem with Git. Thank you for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instalattion of new Git for Windows version 2.14.1.windows.1 solved this problem.